# How make a real-time counter clicks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying to make a banner-switch app.And I count how times user was click on the banner.

```
h4 Count 
= @company.clicks
```

and I want the clicks updated in real-time?How make it?AJAX or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is not the perfect way to achieve real-time, at least not until Rails 5. You can:

a) create a loop that will get the number clicks every X number of seconds (easy to do with jQuery) and updates the DOM

b) use external sevice (like Faye)